# Concatenate Js inside html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I.m using a fancybox here:

```
@foreach($galleries as $gallery)
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
          @if($id != null)
          <a id="{{$id}}"  class="fancybox-buttons img-holder small-img" rel="gallery" title="" data-fancybox-group="button"
               href="/storage/galleries/{{$gallery->image}}">
          @else 
          <a id="{{$gallery->id}}"   class="fancybox-buttons img-holder small-img" rel="gallery" title="{{$gallery->id}}" data-fancybox-group="button"
               href="/storage/galleries/{{$gallery->image}}">
          @endif
              <img src="/storage/galleries/{{$gallery->image}}" alt="img">
          </a>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

I have a fancybox function and the afterload option got a sharing link like this :

```
afterLoad : function() {
    id = this.title;
    this.title = 
       '<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ urlencode(Request::fullUrl())}}/(id variable)" class="btn btn-tw btn-small"><i class="fa fa-twitter right-fa"></i> Share</a>';

        }
```

I want to add this variable id to the href , if there is another workaround with php it would be great too

Comment: @MehravishTemkar i tried it but didnt work, but i solved it now using  '<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ urlencode(Request::fullUrl()) }}/'+id+'" class="btn btn-tw btn-small"><i class="fa fa-twitter right-fa"></i> Share</a>'  thanks man

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the `id` like this :

```
'<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ urlencode(Request::fullUrl())}}/' + id + '" class="btn btn-tw btn-small"><i class="fa fa-twitter right-fa"></i> Share</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer it goes like this :

```
'<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={{ urlencode(Request::fullUrl()) }}/'+id+'" class="btn btn-tw btn-small"><i class="fa fa-twitter right-fa"></i> Share</a>'
```